# $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\geq\int_0^1f(x)dx\int_0^1g(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and monotone decreasing,Prove that$\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\geq\int_0^1f(x)dx\int_0^1g(x)dx$

My attempt is trying to calculate their dispersed sums which seems not work.$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n^2} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{i}{n}) \right)\left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}g(\frac{i}{n}) \right)
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{i}{n})+\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{j}{n})+\sum_{0\leq j<i\leq n-1}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{j}{n})\\
&\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{i}{n})+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(n-i-1)f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{i}{n})+\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}(n-j-1)f(\frac{j}{n})g(\frac{j}{n})\\
&=\frac{2n-1}{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{i}{n})-2\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}if(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{i}{n})-(2n-2)f(\frac{n-1}{n})g(\frac{n-1}{n})
\end{align}$$

but I can't go from above to $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\frac{i}{n})g(\frac{i}{n})$.Does anyone know how to do it.Thank you

Comment: Keyword: the (other) [Chebyshev's inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Integral_Chebyshev_inequality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof, though it is by a different method. Observe that since $f,g$ are both monotone decreasing,
$$
\forall x,y, \qquad (f(x)-g(x))(f(y)-g(y)) \geq 0 \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
In particular, by integrating $(\dagger)$ over $x,y$, we get
\begin{align}
0 &\leq \int_0^1 dy\int_0^1 dx  (f(x)-g(x))(f(y)-g(y)) \\
&= \int_0^1 dy\int_0^1 dx  \left( f(x) g(x) + f(y)g(y) - f(x)g(y) - f(y)g(y)\right)
\end{align}
Can you conclude from there, by breaking this integral in 4 pieces and seeing what emerges?

***Note:** the same will work with the discrete version you are using, but it does not actually help to start with Riemann sums before taking the limit; might as well do it directly.*